# jquery tab selected

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following:

http://jsfiddle.net/orangeJuice/Faa97/

So, ok when you click for examle in "link2" it changes its background-color and also will display the href.

Ok, but...what if I click for the second time in "link2"?? I dont want it to changes its background color again. I would like the background color to stay if Im in the same page.

How could I do that when you are in link2 page the background color stays light-blue?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

How is this? http://jsfiddle.net/Faa97/9/

**Edit**: Code block

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
      $('.link').click(function(){
        $('.browseleftrail').removeClass("selected");
        $(this).parent().addClass("selected");
      });
});
```

Comment: Please consider bringing your jQuery into your answer (to reduce the potential for link-rot, and to keep the answer useful in the event of JS Fiddle going down (as it seems to do, on occasion)).

Comment: Apologies, jQuery has been added.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this.. An easy one is just to use the selected class `.selected-browse-col`, and only trigger the event response when they don't click one with a selected.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div").click(function(){

    $("div").not($(this)).removeClass("selected-browse-col");
    $(this).addClass("selected-browse-col");


});
```

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Faa97/10/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.browseleftrail').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('selected-browse-col').siblings().removeClass('selected-browse-col');
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/Faa97/13/